# Ayuda con imagen en post de facebook

Tags: facebook

Sucede que tengo definido una etiquetas meta para compartir un post de facebook, todo va bien con el post; el detalle esta en que la imagen que detallo en el og:image se ve cortada cuando se hace el post.

[image: captura imagen cortada]

He estado buscando y al parecer se pueden usar las opciones og:image:width y og:image:height

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ absolute_url( asset('http://xpertz.co/bundles/xpertz/assets/images/creative/facebook.jpg')) }}" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="520" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="223" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.xpertz.co/"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1416483605041456"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Xpertz" />
<meta property="og:description" content="¿Sabes si te están dando un salario justo? ¿Sabes cuanto deberías ganar? Xpertz te confirma totalmente gratis cuanto están pagando a personas como tú en el mercado. Regístrate y recibe tu estimado personalizado. #comunidadtransparente #Xpertz"/>
```

Pero no veo cambios sustanciales en como se visualiza la imagen.

Alguien ha tenido experiencia en este tema que me pueda orientar, si debo hacer la imagen mas pequeña actualmente esta de 520 px X 220 aprox.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has revisado que la URL del scraper de facebook se actualice cada vez que haces cambios? Puede ser que lo hayas definido todo bien pero el scraper todavía muestre la imagen antigua.

Puedes actualizar el scraper desde aquí: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0):

### a. Algo que cambia constantemente

La cuestión de los tamaños de imagen es algo que suele cambiar según la red social, e incluso algunas redes sociales cambian de tiempo en tiempo estas especificaciones.

Por eso siempre es bueno tener alguna página de referencia donde puedas consultar los posibles cambios que puedan ocurrir, sobre todo cuando tengas bien configuradas tus imágenes y de repente veas que algo falla... considera entonces que ha debido haber algún cambio en las especificaciones y consulta alguna de estas páginas.

#### Cambios para el 2017 en Facebook

En [esta página](https://makeawebsitehub.com/social-media-image-sizes-cheat-sheet/) vienen indicados los nuevos cambios en Facebook y, siempre este tipo de página te ponen las especificaciones completas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resumiendo:

- Imagen de perfil: 180x180 px
- Imagen de portada: 828 x 315 px
- Imagen compartida: 1200 x 630 px
- Enlace compartido: 1200 x 627 px
- Imagen sobre saltada: 1200 x 717 px

### b. Resetear la imagen

Debido a cuestiones de caché y otras, las imágenes viejas de quedan durante un tiempo almacenadas. Yo tengo en mi sitio una página en la cual la imágen cambia semanalmente. **Siempre** tengo que usar una herramienta que tiene Facebook para que mi imagen se muestre correctamente, pues si cambio ahora mismo el contenido de mi página y trato de compartirla en FB, la imagen que se verá será la anterior.

Para eso existe el [Depurador de errores de contenido compartido](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), yendo a esa página, colocas allí la url de la página que has actualizado, empezando por www. , no es obligatorio poner http primero. Y luego haces clic en el botón **Depurar**. Se mostrará el contenido de tu página con la imagen actual reconocida por Facebook, casi seguro que será la antigua, a no ser que hayas cambiado el contenido hace un tiempo. Si ves en el contenido la imagen actual y se ve bien, no tienes nada que hacer.

Si ves la imagen de forma incorrecta, entonces tienes que presionar en el botón **Volver a extraer**, para que el contenido de la página sea reseteado. Te mostrará la imagen, las urls, una vista previa, etc. A veces tienes que darle dos o tres veces al **volver a extraer**, hasta que te salga el contenido correcto, sobre todo si entras al debugger casi inmediatamente después de haber actualizado el contenido.

Con una imagen con el tamaño según las especificaciones de Facebook y usando el debugger, tu problema debería quedar resuelto.