# ¿Cómo personalizar URL compartida en Facebook?

Tags: php, html, facebook

Necesito encontrar como trabajan sitios como http://yourpast.life/. Cada vez que en Facebook compartes una URL como "yourpast.life/tunombre", dentro de facebook aparece "hey tunombre, en tu vida pasada fuiste XYZ". ¿Cómo lograron hacer eso?

Bien puedo ver cómo funciona pero no me queda claro cómo es que agregan una imagen y una frase exacta en una nueva página o en refresh. Estoy perdido.

Estoy analizando el código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#FindOut').click(function(){
     var name = $("#name").val();
     if ($.trim(name).length>0) {
            var link = 'http://' +'yourpast.life/' + name;
            window.location.href = link;
     }else{  
      alert("Please Enter Your Name")

     }
   })

   $('#try').click(function(){
       var link = 'http://' +'yourpast.life';
       window.location.href = link;
   })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [mira esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66061/ayuda-con-imagen-en-post-de-facebook) o [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5952/compartir-contenido-web-en-google/5968#5968). de todas formas la pregunta es de baja calidad :/

Comment: Muchas gracias Arie CwHat. Entiendo bien la parte en facbook pero no logro replicar el mismo script.

Comment: No, esa página no tiene un contrato con Facebook, estoy seguro. Pero si, necesito lograr eso. Ya he visto que es muy popular este tipo de páginas. Había una que era escribe gokku.com /tunombre y descubre que personaje de dbz eres en realidad*.. En este caso es este script. Enserio, pago por ello. Otro ejemplo de lo mismo
http://howrip.co/

Comment: Estos utilizan la [API de Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) para obtener los datos de la persona, como el nombre, edad, etc (Como si fuera un login, por eso se pide el permiso del usuario para acceder a `X` información) y luego mostran una imagen aleatoria y guardan estos datos en el almacenamiento, para que cuando vuelva la misma persona esta imagen será la misma. Aqui tienes más enlaces para ayudarte - 1 - [Retrieve User Profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi) 2 - [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=facebook+retrieve+person's+name+api)

Comment: @G4ia Es solo un script muy sencillo. Haz una lista de cosas que pudiste haber sido en el pasado u otra cosa, selecciona uno aleatoriamente y muestralo al usuario. Ni siquiera es necesario el API de Facebook, es solo un boton de compartir.

Comment: @G4ia Este sitio no es para contratar gente, la gente responde voluntariamente.

Comment: @G4ia De hecho yo lo borre, puedes checar en mi perfil aqui mismo mi twitter. No te cobraré, te ayudo a elaborarlo con gusto.

Comment: @Gerardo ¿Por qué ayudar a un usuario fuera del sitio cuando podrías poner la solución aquí como respuesta y ayudar a más usuarios que quieran hacer lo mismo?

Comment: Por cierto, para esto no hace falta ni API de Facebook, ni JavaScript, ni jQuery, sólo con PHP y una página simple se puede hacer fácilmente

Comment: según el script que coloqué hace todo el trabajo pero de ahí en adelante no se como le hacen para auto generar un html con esos datos y que en fb aparezca correctamente

Comment: @G4ia en mi respuesta te indico cómo hacen eso. Es usando OpenGraph y los meta datos (mira el punto 4.4)

Answer (score 1):

Esto es realmente sencillo de hacer. Se hace todo en PHP y con .htaccess, sin necesitar absolutamente nada de JavaScript ni de la API de Facebook ni otras historias. Además, sólo necesitarías una pequeña página PHP (y las imágenes que quieras usar).

1. En tu servidor crea un directorio y sube las imágenes de las "profesiones". Sería ideal si el nombre de los ficheros corresponde con el nombre de las profesiones que se definirán luego en el paso 4.1.
2. Configura el servidor para que redireccione todo el tráfico del tipo:

   http://miservidor.com/NOMBRE

   a

   http://miservidor.com?n=NOMBRE

   Esto se puede hacer con una redirección en `.htaccess`. Tengo algo parecido hecho para una página web propia que funciona así:

   ```
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} miservidor.com$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*/)?(.*)$ $1?n=$2
   ```
3. Crea un `index.php` que podría estar vacío si quisieras, aunque realmente vas a querer que tenga una descripción de lo que es el sitio por si alguien entra, que haya algo de contenido.

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
       <head>

       </head>
       <body>
           <!-- Aquí pondrías lo que quisieras, no tiene por qué ser personalizado -->
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
4. En el `index.php`:

   1. Define un array con profesiones
   2. Elige una de las profesiones de manera pseudo-aleatorio: es decir, quieres que sea al azar, pero basado en el valor del nombre. De ese modo siempre que se pase el mismo nombre, se recibirá el mismo valor.
   3. Lee el valor del parámetro (el nombre que se le pasó)
   4. Rellena los metadatos que usa Facebook/LinkedIn/Skype/etc para rellenar sus tarjetas (Twitter usa otros, pero también puede leer estos), con la info de los puntos 4.2 y 4.3. Los metadatos que te interesan son:

      - `og:title`: el título de la página
      - `og:type`: el tipo de la página (te basta con "website")
      - `og:url`: la URL que quieres que muestre Facebook/LinkedIn/Skype/etc)
      - `og:image`: la imagen que quieres que acompañe al enlace en la tarjeta
      - `og:description`: la descripción que aparecerá en la tarjeta.

Con todo eso, el `index.php` se quedaría así:

```
<?php

// array con profesiones
$profesiones = array("informatico", "arquitecto", "monje");

$nombre = isset($_GET["n"]) ? htmlentities($_GET["n"]) : "";
$profesion = $profesiones[ strlen($nombre) % count($profesiones) ];

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hola <?php echo $nombre; ?>, antes eras <?php echo $profesion; ?></title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="Hola <?php echo $nombre; ?>, antes eras <?php echo $profesion; ?>" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://miservidor.com/<?php echo $nombre; ?>" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://miservidor.com/img/<?php echo $profesion; ?>.jpg" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="Pulsa aqui para saber mas sobre tu vida pasada!" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Aquí pondrías lo que quisieras, no tiene por qué ser personalizado -->
    </body>
</html>
```